# Behavior of older NDF file after data purge

Tags: sql-server

If we add a 2nd NDF file to a database, and then later purge a bunch of data from the very large original NDF, will SQL server stop adding to the 2nd NDF and go back to writing to the newly freed space on the 1st NDF, or will it just forget about that one and just continue to write to the 2nd one? If it matters one table takes up most of the space on that original NDF and so only data from that table will be purged.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round robin and proportional fill will still kick in and be used. There is a feedback mechanism to re-evaluate different aspects of this every so often. To answer the question, SQL Server will continue to allocate from both, unless otherwise unable or specified not to.

Comment: Adding this is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver16#file-and-filegroup-fill-strategy).

Comment: Thanks! Marking as answered